# cropping Text Images From Pdf File in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, crop

I have pdf documents which Contains Questions with multiple answers.
And sometimes the Questions and Options of The Questions are images or u called them text images or sketches. What I am doing is actually I am extracting Questions and  options.
But how can I extract these sketches or text images.

I was thinking that those Questions which are Sketches or text images should be cropped but i  the Pdf document have no format .some times the Questions are text and some times images so how can i get these images and if I able to crop the images then how I get the coordinates

 i am sharing the pdf file's image .
[image: pdf file image with questions having images]

[image: pdf file image question without image]

Comment: Is your real question "how to extract images from a pdf including their location (and size)?"

Comment: actually the pictures in this pdf is not actually pictures ther are also like text so i need coordinates to crop them from pdf in c# programatically. do u got it?